# Can somebody add the "sacramentals" tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I wanted to ask several questions about [not limited to Catholic] sacramentals, such as chalices, religious icons, ciborium, etc. Can we add it?

Thanks!

Comment: [It is finished](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sacramentals).

Comment: Well it's already been added, though I'm not sure it would have much use beyond the sacraments tag.

Comment: Well, I haven't seen it before I asked this question.